# golang source code why write in this way

Tags: go, types, interface

I saw some golang code and I don't know how it works! Anyone known ?
Why write in this way ?

```
var _ errcode.ErrorCode = (*StoreTombstonedErr)(nil) // assert implements interface
var _ errcode.ErrorCode = (*StoreBlockedErr)(nil)    // assert implements interface
```

And the source code link is https://github.com/pingcap/pd/blob/0e216a703776c51cb71f324c36b6b94c1d25b62f/server/core/errors.go#L37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used to check the if type T implements an interface I.

```
var _ errcode.ErrorCode = (*StoreTombstonedErr)(nil) // assert implements interface
var _ errcode.ErrorCode = (*StoreBlockedErr)(nil)
```

In above code snippet First line checks that `StoreTombstonedErr` implmenets `errcode.ErrorCode`

While Second line checks that `*StoreBlockedErr` implements `errcode.ErrorCode`.

> You can ask the compiler to check that the type T implements the
>   interface I by attempting an assignment using the zero value for T or
>   pointer to T, as appropriate:

```
type T struct{}
var _ I = T{}       // Verify that T implements I.
var _ I = (*T)(nil) // Verify that *T implements I.
```

If T (or *T, accordingly) doesn't implement I, the mistake will be caught at compile time.

If you wish the users of an interface to explicitly declare that they implement it, you can add a method with a descriptive name to the interface's method set. For example:

```
type Fooer interface {
    Foo()
    ImplementsFooer()
}
```

A type must then implement the ImplementsFooer method to be a Fooer

```
type Bar struct{}
func (b Bar) ImplementsFooer() {}
func (b Bar) Foo() {}
```